# How can I convert high resolution JPG to byte array?

Tags: c#, opencv

I have a 63572 x 63573 High resolution JPG image.
I want to convert the image to byte array and convert byte array to OpenCvsharp.Mat.

the image is grayscale.

I tried to way that below code. However, It occurs 'System.OverflowException'(System.Drawing.dll).

```
 System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filepath);
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
 var data = ms.ToArray();
```

So, I tried to way that below code. However,
It didn't run properly.

```
    var data = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
 using (Mat mat = new Mat(height, width, MatType.CV_8UC1, data))
                {
...

}
```

Comment: That's 4,041,462,756 bytes... what exact error message do you get, rather than 'overflow'?

Comment: I got the message 'System.OverflowException'(System.Drawing.dll)'.
I think it is because when It was loaded an image, it is imported as an RGB image.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-5.0) say: _"[The] array size is limited to a total of 4 billion elements, and to a maximum index of 0X7FEFFFFF in any given dimension **(0X7FFFFFC7 for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures)**.

[...] .NET Framework only: By default, the maximum size of an Array is 2 gigabytes (GB). In a 64-bit environment, you can avoid the size restriction by setting the enabled attribute of the gcAllowVeryLargeObjects configuration element to true in the run-time environment."_

Comment: Does the method for converting `Bitmap` -> `Mat` not work ([documented here](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/wiki/Converting-Image))?

Comment: @Llama I tried the document, It Occurs CV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS..

Comment: I would assume that you'll have the same issue no matter how you construct the `Mat` in that case.